# iPhone SDK: AVAudioRecorder metering -- how to change peakPowerForChannel from decibel into percentage?

Tags: iphone, core-audio, avaudiorecorder, decibel

The AVAudioRecorder in the iPhone SDK can be used to get the peak and average power for a channel, in decibels. The range is between 0db to 160db. What is the calculation used to convert this into a scale between 0 - 10 or something similar that can be used for an audio level meter?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The range is from -160 dB to 0 dB. You probably want to display it in a meter that goes from -90 dB to 0 dB. Displaying it as decibels is actually more useful than as a linear audio level, because the decibels are a logarithmic scale, which means that it more closely approximates how loud we perceive a sound.

That said, you can use this to convert from decibels to linear:

`linear = pow (10, decibels / 20);`

and the reverse:

`decibels = log10 (linear) * 20;`

The range for the above decibels is negative infinity to zero, and for linear is 0.0 to 1.0. When the linear value is 0.0, that is -inf dB; linear at 1.0 is 0 dB.

Comment: What exactly is `20` here?

Comment: When measuring sound intensity in air, the reference value is by convention a sound pressure of 20 micropascals (µPa), the textbook value for the average quietest sound that a healthy young human can hear (at a frequency of 1000 Hz)
https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_relationship_between_dB_decibel_and_dBA_how_to_convert_dB_to_dBA

Answer (score 5):

Apple also implemented a dB to linear amplitude conversion class MeterTable.cpp and MeterTable.h
Look for it in SpeakHere app example.

You can either use their inline function that calculates the value "on-the-fly"

```
inline double DbToAmp(double inDb);
```

OR

create a MeterTable instance to use pre-calculated lookup table.  This stores conversion values in memory so your application can reduce number of calculations.

```
float ValueAt(float inDecibels);
```

NOTE: lookup table is probably needed if you have a lot of other calculations going on at the same time or you need VERY fast processing.

Comment: And the DbToAmp function returns: `pow(10., 0.05 * inDb);`

Comment: Also https://github.com/warrenburton/MeterTableOC if you don't want the slight hassle of c++ files in your project