# Getting sound in decibel

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I want the sound which i am recording from my iPhone mic in decibels. I am using

`[recorder peakPowerForChannel:]`

but it giving in -160 to 0 range and i have requirement of taking 140 dBs as 
a threshold. Can anyone help me with the same…?

Here is the Below sample code which i am trying :

```
NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleLossless] forKey:   AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:22050.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
//  [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12800] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
[recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityLow] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
NSError* error = nil;
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedFile  settings:recordSettings  error:&error];


[recorder prepareToRecord];
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder record];
NSTimer *blowTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: blowTimer
                             forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

-(void)timerTask
{
    [recorder updateMeters];
    float averagePower = [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487734/95309 might provide some insights. I think the gotcha is that your limit might need to be -20 dB, rather than 140.

Comment: but it is crossing -20 while i am doing normal conversation within 1m.